# detecting fragment overlapping

Tags: android, fragment

So I have Parent Layout RelativeLayout, inside 2 frame layout, 1 covering half screen and 1 full screen

```
<FrameLayout id =+@id/ALayout
 layout_width="match_parent" 
 layout_height="wrap_content" />

<FrameLayout id =+@id/BLayout 
 layout_width="match_parent" 
 layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Let's suppose fragment A is added to ALayout. everything is ok Now B is added to BLayout which cover the whole screen. This time nothing got called in fragment A lifecycle. How to know fragment A is covered by B?

I tried `setUserVisibleHint onHiddenChanged isVisible isHidden` and other life cyle methods but nothing got called in this case :(

Comment: You can trigger a callback by yourself to Fragment A when Fragment B is added.

Answer (score 0):

Use Touch listener in Fragment like

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the list_item for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);
    view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.e("FragmentOne Touch",v+"");
            return false;
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```